# conditional rules for sparse matrix

Tags: sparse-arrays

why does the following not work (Table isn't plugging in values for k):

```
m = 3;    
n = 5;
SparseArray[Table[{i_, j_} /; j == i + k n -> 1, {k, 0, m - 1}], {n, m (n + 1)}]
```

instead one seemingly has to jump through hoops and do:

```
SparseArray[Table[{i_, j_} /; j == i + k n -> 1 /. {k -> t}, {t, 0, m - 1}], {n, m (n + 1)}]
```

Comment: If speed on large creation is important, methods posted so far can be handily beat, look at using `ArrayPad` on an appropriate base...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Condition` (`/;`) has attribute `HoldAll`, so `j == i + k n` is not evaluated and the value of `k` never gets there.  `Rule` is not held, so `t` in `{k -> t}` *is* evaluated before replacing `k` in the `Condition`.

---

But it turns out you don't actually need the `Table` here, you can do something like:

```
 SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; (i == Mod[j, n, 1] && j <= m n) -> 1, {n, m (n + 1)}]
```

This is slower than the original for large matrices through.  We can replace the pattern with `Band` to get even faster than the original:

```
SparseArray[Table[Band[{1, (k - 1) n + 1}] -> 1, {k, m}], {n, m (n + 1)}]
```

Comment: looks nice, but for large m and n the mod solution seems to be considerably slower (by a factor of 50)

Comment: @Peter You're right, I guess the `Mod` breaks some of the optimizations so it has to loop over all of the possible `{i,j}` pairs?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how large of m and n you deem "large", but certainly it should be obvious that creating a `Table` for the purposes of populating a `SparseArray` is, to be charitable, counterproductive (I'd use something much more colorful were an engineer working for me to do such things).

Take advantage of the sparse-aware Mathematica functions:

```
ArrayPad[ArrayPad[SparseArray@IdentityMatrix[{n, n}], {{0, 0}, {0, n (m - 1)}}, "Periodic"], {{0, 0}, {0, m}}]
```

Produces same results as yours and the current (only) answer, vastly faster (~60X faster than yours on 500x500 and well over order of magnitude faster than only answer so far). Side benefit - its sparse result needs only about 1/3 the storage compared to your method and existing answer.

N.B. The double padding is a bit faster than re-sparsifying to end dimensions...